# Python Rubiks cube solver - general code comments

Tags: python, html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

I have been learning Python/Flask for the past 5 months outside of full time work and have just finished a first complete version of an app:

- Working site: https://rubiks-cube-solver.herokuapp.com/
- Github link: https://github.com/samjcox/rubiks

The app mostly uses Python, Flask and Bootstrap, with a small amount of JavaScript.

Please can I ask for your comments on the overall code, please chose whichever sections you would like to comment on.  I am interested to know if there are best-practices or better ways to implement what I have done.

I am aware that I have not used 'objects' as much I could have in the python files - I do intend to amend the code to use objects in the near future. I have only included code from the main app.py file below due to Stack Exchange code length limit, so for full context please refer to the github link if you would like.  Thanks.

Main app:

```
# Standard library modules
import os
import datetime
import random
import sqlite3
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from functools import wraps

# Non-standard modules
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask_session import Session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pylibmc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions, HTTPException, InternalServerError
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

# Other files within application
import helpers # Contains functions to support the main routes.
import config # Contains large or repeatedly used data.

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Auto-reload templates
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Ensure responses aren't cached. Sourced from CS50.
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response

# Configure Memcache for session storage, following this Heroku guide:
# https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/flask-memcache
cache = Cache()
cache_servers = os.environ.get('MEMCACHIER_SERVERS')
if cache_servers == None:
    cache.init_app(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
else:
    cache_user = os.environ.get('MEMCACHIER_USERNAME') or ''
    cache_pass = os.environ.get('MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD') or ''
    cache.init_app(app,
        config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'saslmemcached',
                'CACHE_MEMCACHED_SERVERS': cache_servers.split(','),
                'CACHE_MEMCACHED_USERNAME': cache_user,
                'CACHE_MEMCACHED_PASSWORD': cache_pass,
                'CACHE_OPTIONS': { 'behaviors': {
                    # Faster IO
                    'tcp_nodelay': True,
                    # Keep connection alive
                    'tcp_keepalive': True,
                    # Timeout for set/get requests
                    'connect_timeout': 2000, # ms
                    'send_timeout': 750 * 1000, # us
                    'receive_timeout': 750 * 1000, # us
                    '_poll_timeout': 2000, # ms
                    # Better failover
                    'ketama': True,
                    'remove_failed': 1,
                    'retry_timeout': 2,
                    'dead_timeout': 30}}})
    app.config.update(
        SESSION_TYPE = 'memcached',
        SESSION_MEMCACHED =
            pylibmc.Client(cache_servers.split(','), binary=True,
                            username=cache_user, password=cache_pass,
                            behaviors={
                                # Faster IO
                                'tcp_nodelay': True,
                                # Keep connection alive
                                'tcp_keepalive': True,
                                # Timeout for set/get requests
                                'connect_timeout': 2000, # ms
                                'send_timeout': 750 * 1000, # us
                                'receive_timeout': 750 * 1000, # us
                                '_poll_timeout': 2000, # ms
                                # Better failover
                                'ketama': True,
                                'remove_failed': 1,
                                'retry_timeout': 2,
                                'dead_timeout': 30,
                            })
    )
Session(app)

# TEMPORARY FOR FLASK LOCAL TESTING ONLY.
# Configure session to use filesystem,
# (instead of signed cookies), sourced from CS50.
# app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
# app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
# app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
# Session(app)

# SQLalchemy has removed support for postgress:// scheme which is used
# by Heroku Postgres, the below maintains compatibility.
# https://help.heroku.com/ZKNTJQSK/why-is-sqlalchemy-1-4-x-not-connecting-to-heroku-postgres
uri = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
if uri.startswith("postgres://"):
    uri = uri.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)

# Connect to database.
engine = create_engine(uri)
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

# Commit and close database.
def db_close():
    db.commit()
    db.close()

# Check user is logged in, sourced from CS50.
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get("user_id") is None:
            print("LOGIN_REQUIRED - user_id is None.")
            return redirect("/login")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function


# Login an already registered user.
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    # Clear previous user_id.
    session.clear()

    # If reached by get, present login form.
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("login.html")

    # If reached by post, check input and then log the user in.
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Ensure username was entered.
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            flash("Username was not entered, please enter a username.")
            return render_template("/login.html")
        else:
            username = request.form.get("username")
        # Ensure password was entered.
        if not request.form.get("password"):
            flash("Password was not entered, please enter password.")
            return render_template("/login.html")
        # Check database for username and password.
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (:username)"
        data = {"username": username}
        rows = db.execute(SQL, data).fetchall()
        # Commit & close database connection.
        db_close()
        # Check if password matches or if no password found in database.
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hashed_password"], request.form.get("password")):
            flash("Username and/or password does not match.")
            return render_template("/login.html")
        # Remember user has logged in and set current cube to blank.
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
        session["current_cube_id"] = 0
        session["username"] = username
        # Redirect to homepage.
        return redirect("/")


# Logout the current user.
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()
    # Redirect user to login form
    return redirect("/")


# Register a new user.
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    # If user has not submitted form information (arrived via GET).
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")

    # If user has submitted a form (arrived via POST).
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Check that username has been entered.
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            flash("Username required.")
            return redirect("/register")
        else:
            username = request.form.get("username")
        # Check that username does not already exist.
        SQL = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username"
        data = {"username": username}
        existing_username = db.execute(SQL, data).fetchall()
        # Close database connection.
        db_close()
        # If username already exists, alert user and return.
        if existing_username:
            flash("Username " + username + " already exists.")
            return redirect("/register")
        # Check that password has been entered.
        password = request.form.get("password")
        if not password:
            flash("Password required.")
            return redirect("/register")
        # Check that second password entry matches the first.
        if not password == request.form.get("confirmation"):
            flash("Passwords do not match.")
            return redirect("/register")
        # Check password has at least 8 characters.
        if len(password) < 8:
            flash("Password must contain at least 8 characters.")
            return redirect("/register")
        # Check password has at least 1 number.
        if not any(character.isdigit() for character in password):
            flash("Password must contain at least 1 number.")
            return redirect("/register")
        # Hash password
        hashed = generate_password_hash(password, "sha256")
        # Submit username and hashed password to database.
        SQL = "INSERT INTO users (username, hashed_password) VALUES (:username, :hashed)"
        data = {"username": username, "hashed": hashed}
        db.execute(SQL, data)
        # Automatically log user in.
        SQL = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = (:username)"
        data = {"username": username}
        user_id = db.execute(SQL, data).fetchall()
        session['user_id'] = user_id[0]["id"]
        session["username"] = username
        # Commit & close database connection.
        db_close()
        # Send user to homepage after registration and login complete.
        flash(f"You have been registered successfully with username: {username}.")
        return redirect("/")


# Create a Guest user.
@app.route("/guest")
def guest():
        # Submit generic guest username in order to get a unique user ID.
        SQL = "INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (:username)"
        data = {"username": "guest tbc"}
        db.execute(SQL, data)
        # Get user ID to include the ID in the guest username.
        SQL = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = (:username)"
        data = {"username": "guest tbc"}
        user_rows = db.execute(SQL, data).fetchone()
        user_id = user_rows[0]
        # Update generic guest username to include their user ID.
        new_guest_username = f"Guest {user_id}"
        SQL = "UPDATE users SET (username) = row(:new_guest_username) WHERE (id) = (:user_id)"
        data = ({"new_guest_username": new_guest_username, "user_id": user_id})
        db.execute(SQL, data)
        # Automatically log user in.
        session['user_id'] = user_id
        session["username"] = new_guest_username
        # Commit & close database connection.
        db_close()
        # Send user to homepage after registration and login complete.
        return redirect("/")


# Load this users cubes, ready for display.
def load_users_cubes():
    # Display previously entered cubes for this user.
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM cubes WHERE user_id = (:user_id) ORDER BY id DESC"
    data = {"user_id": session["user_id"]}
    users_cubes = db.execute(SQL, data).fetchall()
    # Close database connection.
    db_close()
    return users_cubes


# Default route, homepage.
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    # Load users cubes and render homepage.
    users_cubes = load_users_cubes()
    return render_template("index.html", users_cubes=users_cubes)


# Display only loading table.
@app.route("/load_page", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def load_page():
    # Load users cubes and render load page.
    users_cubes = load_users_cubes()
    return render_template("load.html", users_cubes=users_cubes)


# Route to delete existing cube.
@app.route("/delete_cube", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def delete_cube():
    # Delete the selected cube from the database.
    cube_to_delete = request.form.get("delete")
    SQL = "DELETE FROM cubes WHERE id = :cube_to_delete"
    data = {"cube_to_delete": cube_to_delete}
    db.execute(SQL, data)
    # Commit & close database connection.
    db_close()
    # If sessions current cube is the cube to be deleted, set current cube to zero.
    if session["current_cube_id"] == cube_to_delete:
        session["current_cube_id"] = 0
    # Alert user to successful deletion and return to homepage.
    flash("Cube ID " + cube_to_delete + " successfully deleted.")
    return redirect("/")


# Delete all cubes of this user.
@app.route("/delete_all_cubes", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def delete_all_cubes():
    # Delete all cubes that belong to this user.
    SQL = "DELETE FROM cubes WHERE user_id = :user_id"
    data = {"user_id": session["user_id"]}
    db.execute(SQL, data)
    # Commit & close database connection.
    db_close()
    # Set current cube to zero.
    session["current_cube_id"] = 0
    # Alert user to successful deletion and return to homepage.
    flash("All your cubes have now been successfully deleted.")
    return redirect("/")


# Create blank cube and store ID
def create_cube():
    # Determine time/date cube created, converted to users local time.
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    created = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    # Create new cube in database to generate cube ID number.
    SQL = "INSERT INTO cubes (user_id, created) VALUES (:user_id, :created)"
    data = {"user_id": session["user_id"], "created": created}
    db.execute(SQL, data)
    # Find the ID of the cube that has just been created.
    SQL = "SELECT id FROM cubes WHERE user_id = :user_id ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1"
    data = {"user_id": session["user_id"]}
    cube_id_list = db.execute(SQL, data).fetchall()
    # Commit & close database connection.
    db_close()
    # Store Id of this new cube and clear the session cube.
    cube_id = cube_id_list[0]['id']
    session["current_cube_id"] = cube_id
    session["cube"] = []


# Check if cube is valid (correct number of colours accounted for):
def check_cube():
    # Create colour_check dictionary and set counts to zero.
    colour_check = dict.fromkeys(config.colours)
    for colour in colour_check:
        colour_check[colour] = 0

    # Sum the total number of each colour.
    print("SESSION CUBE:")
    print(session["cube"])
    for square in session["cube"]:
        for colour in config.colours:
            if session["cube"][square] == colour:
                colour_check[colour] = colour_check[colour] + 1
                break

    # Initiate the list of errors, to be populated next.
    session["errors"] = []

    # Check if colour totals are too many or too few.
    for colour in colour_check:
        # There should be 9 of each colour.
        if colour_check[colour] == 9:
            continue
        elif colour_check[colour] < 9:
            session["errors"].append("Too few " + colour + " squares.")
            continue
        elif colour_check[colour] > 9:
            session["errors"].append("Too many " + colour + " squares.")

    # If no errors, confirm the cube is correct and proceed.
    if not session["errors"]:
        # Add "no errors" & progress status to database.
        progress = helpers.solve_progress(session["cube"])
        SQL = "UPDATE cubes SET (input_check, stage) = ('Input Ok', :stage) WHERE (id) = (:cube_id);"
        data = ({"stage": progress, "cube_id": session["current_cube_id"]}, )
        db.execute(SQL, data)
        # Commit & close database connection.
        db_close()
        print("CHECK_CUBE - Completed with no errors.")
        return redirect("/solve")

    # If errors found, list those errors and ask user to correct.
    else:
        # Load "amend" page to display errors and resolve them.
        SQL = "UPDATE cubes SET (input_check) = row('Error') WHERE (id) = (:cube_id);"
        data = ({"message": 'Error', "cube_id": session["current_cube_id"]})
        db.execute(SQL, data)
        # Commit & close database connection.
        db_close()
        # Flash message to advise that error needs to be resolved.
        flash("Errors found in your cube entry, please resolve before solving.")
        print("CHECK CUBE - Errors found.")
        return redirect("/amend")


# Try to solve with random moves (it won't solve the cube).
@app.route("/solve_randomly")
@login_required
def solve_randomly():
    # Load session cube, define number of moves & initialise counter.
    cube = session["cube"]
    max_number_of_moves = 100000
    move_count = 0
    # Make random moves until cube is solved or move limit reached.
    for move in range(0, max_number_of_moves):
        # If cube is solved, end for loop.
        if helpers.solve_progress(cube) == 8:
            break
        # If cube is not solved, make random move to cube.
        else:
            move_count = move_count + 1
            cube = helpers.random_move(cube)
    # Update session cube with resulting cube.
    for square in config.squares:
        session["cube"][square] = cube[square]
    # Advise user moves were made and return.
    flash(str(move_count) + " randomly picked moves were made.")
    return redirect("/solve")


# Provide random moves to user, for user to randomise real-life cube.
# This will generte a list of moves to make; not amend the cube itself.
# Number of random moves to make will default to 30 unless flask url
# argument received to state otherwise.
@app.route("/randomise_user_cube", defaults={"random_moves":30})
@app.route("/randomise_user_cube/<int:random_moves>")
@login_required
def randomise_user_cube(random_moves):
    # Initialise moves list & move counter.
    random_moves_list = []
    move_count = 0
    # Randomly make moves to cube until max count reached.
    while move_count < random_moves:
        # Randomly select a number between 0 and 11 inclusive.
        y = random.randint(0, 11)
        # Use random number to select a move from list of moves.
        move = config.possible_moves[y]
        # Add move to list of moves to make.
        random_moves_list.append(move)
        # Remove uncesseray/inefficient moves.
        random_moves_list = helpers.improve_efficiency(random_moves_list)
        # Update move_count.
        move_count = len(random_moves_list)
    # Return list of random moves.
    return render_template("randomiser.html", random_moves_list=random_moves_list)


# Randomise a solved cube to ensure it can actually be solved.
@app.route("/random_cube")
@login_required
def random_cube():
    # Load solved cube.
    cube = config.solved_cube
    # Define number of random moves to make.
    random_moves = 50
    # Make random moves.
    for x in range(0, random_moves):
        cube = helpers.random_move(cube)
    # Create new cube in databse:
    create_cube()
    # Enter the randomised data into the dictionary:
    for square in cube:
        # Update database with colour of each square. There may be a
        # better way to update 54 SQL columns, to be investigated.
        # Note that as the input to the below SQL query is hard-coded,
        # there should be no risk of SQL injection attack.
        SQL = f"UPDATE cubes SET {square} = :square WHERE id = :cube_id"
        data = {"square": cube[square], "cube_id": session["current_cube_id"]}
        db.execute(SQL, data)
    # Commit & close database connection.
    db_close()
    # Update session cube & return cube check:
    session["cube"] = cube
    print("RANDOM CUBE - Function complete.")
    return check_cube()


# Route to create new cube.
@app.route("/enter", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def enter():

    if request.method == "GET":
        # Display blank template to entre new cube.
        return render_template("enter.html", squares=config.squares, colour_initials=config.colour_initials)

    if request.method == "POST":
        # Create empty dictionary of squares, ready for user input.
        cube = dict.fromkeys(config.squares)
        # Create new cube in database:
        create_cube()
        # Enter the submitted data into the dictionary:
        # Note that as the input to the below SQL query is hard-coded,
        # there should be no risk of SQL injection attack.
        for square in cube:
            square_colour = request.form.get(square)
            cube[square] = square_colour
            SQL = f"UPDATE cubes SET {square} = :square_colour WHERE id = :cube_id"
            data = {"square_colour": square_colour, "cube_id": session["current_cube_id"]}
            db.execute(SQL, data)
        # Commit & close database connection.
        db_close()
        # Update session cube & return cube check:
        session["cube"] = cube
        return check_cube()


@app.route("/load", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def load():
    # Replace current session cube id with the clicked cube_id.
    cube_to_load = request.form.get("load")
    session["current_cube_id"] = cube_to_load
    # Load cube from database into session cube.
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM cubes WHERE id = :cube_to_load"
    data = {"cube_to_load": cube_to_load}
    cube_loading = db.execute(SQL, data)
    # Convert to dictionary from row object to allow lookup by key.
    list = [dict(row) for row in cube_loading]
    session["cube"] = list[0]
    # Commit & close database connection.
    db_close()
    return check_cube()


@app.route("/amend_from_list", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def amend_from_list():
    # Replace current session cube with clicked cube.
    cube_to_amend = request.form.get("amend")
    session["current_cube_id"] = cube_to_amend
    # Load cube from database into session cube.
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM cubes WHERE id = :cube_to_amend"
    data = {"cube_to_amend": cube_to_amend}
    cube_loading = db.execute(SQL, data).fetchall()
    session["cube"] = cube_loading[0]
    # Commit & close database connection.
    db_close()
    return redirect("/amend")


@app.route("/copy", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def copy():
    # Load cube to be copied into temporary dictionary.
    cube_id_to_copy = request.form.get("copy")
    # Load cube from database into temp cube.
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM cubes WHERE id = :cube_id_to_copy"
    data = {"cube_id_to_copy": cube_id_to_copy}
    cube_loading = db.execute(SQL, data)
    # Convert to dictionary from row object to allow lookup by key.
    list = [dict(row) for row in cube_loading]
    temp_cube = list[0]
    # Create new blank cube, and make current session cube.
    create_cube()
    # Populate curret session cube with previous cube contents.
    session["cube"] = temp_cube
    session["cube"]["id"] = session["current_cube_id"]
    # Save new cube contents to database.
    # Note that as the input to the below SQL query is hard-coded,
    # there should be no risk of SQL injection attack.
    for item in temp_cube:
        SQL = f"UPDATE cubes SET {item} = (:cube_item) WHERE (id) = (:cube_id)"
        data = {"cube_item": session["cube"][item], "cube_id": session["current_cube_id"]}
        db.execute(SQL, data)
    # Commit & close database connection.
    db_close()
    # Flash message to user then proceed to home page.
    flash("Copy of Cube ID " + str(cube_id_to_copy) + ", created as new Cube ID " + str(session["current_cube_id"]))
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/amend", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def amend():
    # If loading page prior to data entry,
    # display squares based on current session cube.
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("amend.html", squares=config.squares, colour_initials=config.colour_initials, cube=session["cube"])

    # If new data submitted:
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Update database with user input from form.
        # Note that as the input to the below SQL query is hard-coded,
        # there should be no risk of SQL injection attack.
        cube = session["cube"]
        for square in config.squares:
            square_colour = request.form.get(square)
            cube[square] = square_colour
            SQL = f"UPDATE cubes SET {square} = (:colour) WHERE (id) = (:cube_id);"
            data = ({"colour": square_colour, "cube_id": session["current_cube_id"]})
            db.execute(SQL, data)
        # Commit & close database connection.
        db_close()
        # Update session cube & return cube check:
        session["cube"] = cube
        return check_cube()


@app.route("/solve", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def solve():
    print("SOLVE - Start solve function.")
    # Take current session cube and check progress.
    current_cube_id = session["current_cube_id"]
    progress = helpers.solve_progress(session["cube"])
    # Update solve progress in database.
    SQL = "UPDATE cubes SET (stage) = row(:progress) WHERE (id) = (:cube_id);"
    data = ({"progress": progress, "cube_id": session["current_cube_id"]}, )
    db.execute(SQL, data)
    # Commit & close database connection.
    db_close()
    print("SOLVE - Progress stage found to be " + str(progress))
    
    # If cube is completed already, show 'complete' page.
    if progress == 8:
        return render_template("complete.html")

    # Else if cube is not solved, determine next move required.
    else:
        # Start with "next_cube_colours" matching current cube, ready
        # for moves to be mdae.
        session["next_cube_colours"] = session["cube"]
        # Create list of moves required to
        # progress to solve the current stage of the cube.
        next_actions_list = helpers.next_action()
        # Improve efficiency of moves in next_actions_list.
        next_actions_list = helpers.improve_efficiency(next_actions_list)
        # Look up nick name of current stage.
        stage_name = config.stage_names[progress]
        # Render solve page.
        return render_template("solve.html", next_actions_list=next_actions_list, squares=config.squares, cube=session["cube"], next_cube=session["next_cube_colours"], current_cube_id=session["current_cube_id"], progress=progress, stage_name=stage_name)


@app.route("/solve_entirely")
@login_required
def solve_entirely():
    print("SOLVE ENTIRELY - Single stage solve function started.")
    # Initialise list for required moves.
    complete_solve_list = []
    # Prepare temp dictionary.
    session["next_cube_colours"] = session["cube"]
    # Take current session cube and check progress.
    current_cube_id = session["current_cube_id"]
    progress = helpers.solve_progress(session["cube"])
    # Record stage at which cube started, to correctly display
    # the progress bar and stage description on the page.
    starting_progress = progress

    # If cube is completed already, show 'complete' page.
    if progress == 8:
        print("SOLVE ENTIRELY - Solving stage is 8.")
        # Cube already solved, nothing to do.
        return render_template("complete.html")

    # Else if cube is before the final stage, continue to loop round, appending to
    # list of moves required until cube is solved.
    while progress < 7:
        print("SOLVE ENTIRELY - Solving stage less than 7.")
        # Loop through each solve stage.
        # Append moves required for that solve stage to the overall list.
        next_moves_list = helpers.next_action()
        for move in next_moves_list:
            complete_solve_list.append(move)
        # Check if the above moves have solved the cube,
        # in order to break the while loop.
        progress = helpers.solve_progress(session["next_cube_colours"])

    # Else the stage must be 7 (last stage) so determine moves for
    # final stage then render page with list of moves.
    else:
        print("SOLVE ENTIRELY - Solving stage is equal to 7.")
        # Append moves required for that solve stage to the overall list.
        next_moves_list = helpers.next_action()
        for move in next_moves_list:
            complete_solve_list.append(move)
        # Improve efficiency of moves in next_actions_list and render.
        next_actions_list = helpers.improve_efficiency(complete_solve_list)
        # Look up nick name of current stage.
        stage_name = config.stage_names[progress]
        # Render solve page.
        return render_template("solve.html", next_actions_list=complete_solve_list, squares=config.squares, cube=session["cube"], next_cube=session["next_cube_colours"], current_cube_id=session["current_cube_id"], progress=starting_progress, stage_name=stage_name)


# Function to record the user has correctly followed the moves of this stage,
# and loop back into the solve function.
@app.route("/next_stage")
@login_required
def next_stage():
    # User has confirmed that they made the moves correctly, so
    # update session cube with next_cube_colours, then allowing
    # the solve to continue from that point. 
    for square in config.squares:
        session["cube"][square] = session["next_cube_colours"][square]
        # Update the database with new cube state.
        # Note that as the input to the below SQL query is hard-coded,
        # there should be no risk of SQL injection attack.
        SQL = f"UPDATE cubes SET {square} = (:colour) WHERE (id) = (:cube_id)"
        data = ({"square": square, "colour": session['cube'][square], "cube_id": session["current_cube_id"]})
        db.execute(SQL, data)
    # Commit & close database connection.
    db_close()
    print("NEXT_STAGE - Function complete.")
    # Return to solve page to solve this new cube state.
    return redirect("/solve")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your `Configure Memcache` section into a function to clean up the global namespace, even if you unconditionally call it from the global namespace.

Likewise, instead of commenting out

```
# TEMPORARY FOR FLASK LOCAL TESTING ONLY.
# Configure session to use filesystem,
# (instead of signed cookies), sourced from CS50.
# app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
# app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
# app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
# Session(app)
```

you can write out a function that calls `app.config.update({ ...` rather than repeated assignments, and simply comment out the call to it. Advantages to this approach include that your basic syntax will be verified without the code being executed.

Your `behaviors` dict is identical in two places, so factor out a variable for it.

`uri = uri.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://"` is too permissive - it will search the entire string for the indicated scheme. A regex-replace starting with the start-caret `^` will avoid this problem.

I find

```
methods=["GET", "POST"]
```

better-expressed as

```
methods=('GET', 'POST')
```

since tuples are immutable and these methods will never change.

This block:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    # Clear previous user_id.
    session.clear()

    # If reached by get, present login form.
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("login.html")

    # If reached by post, check input and then log the user in.
    if request.method == "POST":
```

indicates that you actually need two different functions, each accepting only one method, so that you do not have to write any switching logic.

This block:

```
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (:username)"
        data = {"username": username}
        rows = db.execute(SQL, data).fetchall()
        # Commit & close database connection.
        db_close()
```

has a collection of issues:

- You should not be committing, since you didn't write anything
- You shouldn't be closing the connection; instead you should release the connection to a connection pool
- Assuming that you have a unique constraint on the username, which you should, you should only be fetching one row and not all rows. Or you could tuple-unpack

```
    user_row, = user_rows
```

to both get the only row and assert that there's only one row.

This block:

```
    session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
    session["current_cube_id"] = 0
    session["username"] = username
```

should also use an `update()` instead of repeated key assignment.

This:

```
created = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

should not use `strftime`, and should pass the `datetime` directly to SQLAlchemy.

This:

```
            colour_check[colour] = colour_check[colour] + 1
```

can use in-place addition:

```
            colour_check[colour] += 1
```

This block:

```
    if colour_check[colour] == 9:
        continue
    elif colour_check[colour] < 9:
        session["errors"].append("Too few " + colour + " squares.")
        continue
    elif colour_check[colour] > 9:
        session["errors"].append("Too many " + colour + " squares.")
```

can be reduced to

```
    if colour_check[colour] < 9:
        session["errors"].append("Too few " + colour + " squares.")
    elif colour_check[colour] > 9:
        session["errors"].append("Too many " + colour + " squares.")
```

since the equality condition is a no-op and this is the only code in the loop.

Statements such as

```
print("CHECK CUBE - Errors found.")
```

should be converted into real logging statements, since this is a web service and not an interactive console application.

Literals such as the one in

```
max_number_of_moves = 100000
```

are more nicely expressed with a thousands-separator:

```
max_number_of_moves = 100_000
```

Since `x` is not used here:

```
for x in range(0, random_moves):
```

it can be reduced to

```
for _ in range(random_moves):
```

In this statement:

```
        SQL = f"UPDATE cubes SET {square} = :square_colour WHERE id = :cube_id"
```

you have an injection vulnerability. `square` comes from your configuration, so it may not be easy for this vulnerability to be exploited, but better safe than sorry: make it a normal parameter, just like your other parameters. You may need to get fancy in passing a literal column, but that raises a broader point: Why are you using SQLAlchemy? You have no ORM code at all, nor any models. You could cut through to `psycopg`.

This statement:

```
list = [dict(row) for row in cube_loading]
```

shadows a critical built-in, `list`; so find a different variable name.

This:

```
flash("Copy of Cube ID " + str(cube_id_to_copy) + ", created as new Cube ID " + str(session["current_cube_id"]))
```

would be better-off using f-strings:

```
flash(f"Copy of Cube ID {cube_id_to_copy}, created as new Cube ID {session['current_cube_id']}")
```

Aside from all of the above fine-grained stuff, all of your logic code is baked straight into your Flask handlers. Make an attempt to separate these out into business logic functions in a separate file.